# Add Items in RadComboBox dynamically in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I'm trying to add `Items` to `RadComboBox` dynamically. It's supposed to work like this: I have an editable `RadComboBox` and a `Button`. Any text I type into `RadComboBox` should be saved as a new `Item` on a `Button_Click` and I should be able to see it in a dropdown list and select it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: So, what have you tried? What is the question?

Comment: The question is how is it done. I tried adding an item based on text input. something like `comboboxName.Items.Add(comboboxName.Text)` or `comboboxName.Insert[i]` but it doesnt save it, it doesn't show in dropdown

Comment: What happened when you read the documentation on that Add method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would like you to read this in the Telerik documentation: [docs](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radcombobox/populating-with-data/binding-to-object)

It will help you understand how bindings work for the RadComboBox.

How would I solve your problem? I'd follow these steps:

- Bind your RadComboBox to an `ObservableCollection<Item>`. Make sure that `Item` implements `onPropertyChanged()`
- Execute an event when a button is pressed (either through just code-behind, but I prefer ICommand, MVVM style)
- In the event I described above, create an `Item` and add it to your `ObservableCollection<Item>`.

If you have a problem following any of those steps, put a comment below and I'll try to help.